# about mysql select field type of `blob`

Tags: mysql, blob

I have a question about mysql select field type of `blob`, when I select like "[image]" it's  garbled
but i use the navicat export sql like"
 [image]"
I don't know what's type of like "0xFADE571FDC6C7ADBD94444D4562886F8874577843B8F34AF" data 
and I want to select `blob` field print data like "0xFADE571FDC6C7ADBD94444D4562886F8874577843B8F34AF"
what should i do

Comment: A) It's a binary field, so what do you expect? B) Please post plain text instead of huge, mostly empty screenshots.

Comment: @tadman I want to use sql like "select encryptedPassword from entry where id = 1 " to select binary field and display binary data like "0xFADE571FDC6C7ADBD94444D4562886F8874577843B8F34AF" I will make database backup

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT HEX(encryptedPassword)` instead?

Comment: thanks reminded @tadman

Answer (score 2):

BLOB is used for storing binary data.

TEXT maybe used to store strings.

INTEGER maybe used to store HEX values and then you may use `HEX(hex_col)` while printing it using `select`.

You may use BINARY to store hex and then use `HEX(hex_col)` while displaying the values.

Fiddle: [Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b6f7e5/1)

Refer:

[Storing hexadecimal values as binary in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712934/storing-hexadecimal-values-as-binary-in-mysql)
and
[Hex literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)

Comment: @jasondayee good to know it helped. You may [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).